# PHP Match string with numbers and get next number (as Year)

Tags: php

These are my strings

```
2012-13
2013-14
2014-15
2015-16
2016-17
2017-18
```

I my string is `2014-15` as current financial year, I want my next my next financial year as `2015-16`

How can I achieve this with `PHP`? I get these year list form mysql table, but I want next financial year in `php`

Comment: `explode` by `-` and +1 each element ?

Comment: you tagged as mysql, but nothing to support the question

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, that tag was under `Suggested Tags` list. So I added that.

Comment: you have been given answers below. Give those a try ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$financial_year =   "2012-13";

$fin_array      =   explode("-", $financial_year);
$next_fin_array[0]   =  $fin_array[0] + 1;
$next_fin_array[1]   =  $fin_array[1] + 1;

$next_financial_year =  implode("-", $next_fin_array); // Gives 2013-14
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myStr = '2014-15';
$yr1 = (int) substr($myStr, 0, 4);
$yr2 = (int) substr($myStr, -2);
echo ($yr1+1).'-'.($yr2+1);
// 2015-16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$financeYear = DateTime::createFromFormat ( "Y-d" ,"2014-15");
$financeYear->modify('+ 1 year');

echo $financeYear->format("Y-d");
```

Result

```
2015-15
```